# With Universal SSR (Server Side Rendering), what do I do after I've built the production version?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I've managed to follow the Angular.io techniques on Angular Universal: Server-Side Rendering (https://angular.io/guide/universal).

I get to the end, everything runs fine with no errors, and now my dist folder is separated nicely like so:

```
/dist
    /browser
    /server
    /server.js
```

npm run serve:ssr works great, website shows fantastic and most importantly I can see everything compiled nicely in the page source.

Unfortunately, all documentation seems to stop there, so my website is on `localhost:4000`.

Before rendering I was just uploading everything inside `/dist` to my web server and it worked.

I've tried this with my current `/dist` setup, and I get a forbidden message from my web server. I aim at `/server.js` and I see the source code.

Any clue as to where I go from here? So sorry if it's dumb!!

Comment: Where plain angular can be served as purely static assets, if you're using SSR you'll need to ensure that it's running on a server somewhere. In other words, you can't simply point at a JS file, you need to make sure that server actually runs that JS file

Comment: I see! Would I be correct in saying that I would need some sort of dedicated server as opposed to just a standard website host?

Comment: That's right, yes. It will use `express` to serve the content, so any guides you find about deploying express apps should be applicable

Comment: Hi @Marshiewooooooo! To add onto what user184994 said, it looks like you're reaching a point where learning *nginx* (pronounced engine X) maybe of interest to you! It's a server engine that makes it incredibly easy to manage hosting ports (say, for front vs. back api or a universal express app). Good luck moving forwards!

Comment: I appreciate your input guys. I'm just struggling now to get my head around how to run this server.js on my virtual server. Every documentation I had read is intended for local use. I can actually host this using npm run serve:ssr but obviously this is intended for local use, as it uses localhost:4000.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a webserver to handle requests and redirect them to nodejs universal server if the file cannot be served statically.

Example with nginx

```
location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri @universal;
  }

  #Transfer to angular universal handler
  location @universal{

        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  }
```